# Mother in law damaged new car

Tags: toyota, corolla

My mother in law drove over a center divider in her brand new corolla (which we bought her )

The only damage I can see is this area of the undercarriage, under the driver seat.

Being a new vehicle, I can’t find much in the way of a diagram or schematic. Anyone have any idea what this is or it’s purpose?

Thanks in advance! [image]

Comment: Can't see much detail in that pic, take it to the dealer and they will know exactly what to check for. Insurance may, or may not, cover any damage.

Comment: Looks like a cover panel got ripped off, take it to a body shop for further inspection.

Comment: It's rarely worth making an insurance claim for self-inflicted damage. They'll want their money back somehow. When it's on a TP's insurance, it is them who takes the hit in premiums.

Comment: That makes sense Moab. I’m gonna put it on jack stands to compare the two sides. 

I think we will skip going thru insurance. Not much of a way to explain driving over the median... 

Thanks to everyone for responding.

Comment: Should this lady be driving?